# Transparent applicationbar and virtualizing listboxes - WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, listbox, virtualization

I got an app with alot of views containing a listbox in each. All the views also have an applicationbar. What i wanted to do is have the appbar transparent with an opacity of 0.5 as long as its not activated, then set opacity to 0.99 as long as its activated (pulled up). I was able to do this as long as my listboxes were encapsulated in a scrollviewer. The problem is my app use alot of memory, so i had to make the listboxes virtualizing. To do this i had to remove the scrollviewers. That caused my lists to no longer be visible through the applicationbar, even though it is still transparent (i can see that). So you can see my problem: The situation now is that i have to choose between virtualizating listboxes or transparent applicationbar. Do anyone know a solution, or atleast know the explanation to why this isnt working? Thanks alot!

Comment: Can't understand why listbox is not visible through application bar. Maybe problem is in another place: listbox not stretched to the bottom etc...

Comment: It actually seems so. Setting the height of the listbox to 1000 "fixes" the problem, but then the list stops after 1000 pixels. The problem here i that i dont know how long the lists can get; sometimes i might get 2 items, and other times maybe up to 200

Comment: Tried setting verticalalignment and verticalcontentaligntment to stretch, and tried to set maxheight="30000". Nothing worked, and i cant set the height to a set number, since as i mentioned, i dont know the length of the list. Hmmm, any suggestions?

Comment: Any chance you can post the XAML of the affected view to pastebin or similar sites?

Comment: sure, here you go. this is only showing the second pivotitem and the applicationbar. The list in the first pivotitem is wrapped in a scrollviewer, and is visible through the appbar. http://pastebin.com/xePmeCpW

Comment: I reduced the bottom-margin of the listboxes, and it did the trick, although, id like to have a bit more margin. Oh well, this'll do